# Fitting a Spread into ARIMA AR(1) process

Tags: arbitrage, forecasting, spread, arima

I'm a newbie to econometrics. I've simply ran a regression and have coefficient values of the variables. I'm running a regression for a crypto data, and I've gotten the Spread of the variables. To forecast, I'll need to fit this spread into ARIMA AR(1) process after finding the best fit is AR(1).

This is the scenario. Configuring a tradable mean for a time series data is what I'm trying to achieve. The steps I've taken are creating a regression using OLS from the first difference of the time series data.

From this I got the tradable formula, which is a spread between the variables used. It's now time to forecast using ARMA model.

I created the ACF and PACF charts using the residuals from the OLS model, and got to know it's an AR(1) process.

If the spread of the difference between the variables I'll like to know how to fit the spread into this AR(1) process of ARMA.

Please, kindly help out.

Comment: I think you need to explain what you mean by fitting the spread into your AR(1) model. You already fit the model; how can you then put the spread into that model after it is fitted? Also, it is not clear if you are trying to estimate performance in light of transactions costs, finding opportunities when trading would exceed costs of crossing the spread at entry and exit, or trying to use the spread to better predict prices even though bid-ask bounce is not tradable unless you are a market maker. It is not clear what you are trying to do, so it is not really possible to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks @kurtosis, I'm sure I'd got my language wrong as I'm just catching up with the keywords in quantitative statistics. Let me share this thesis in following with you. Probably I'm just playing with words inordinately.

Comment: This is the thesis in following. I'm sure you're right that I've already done this fitting. But I got confused when in the documents it's stated that spread is fitted into ARIMA AR (1) process. Please, what does that mean?https://www.researchgate.net/publication/327163916_Constructing_Cointegrated_Cryptocurrency_Portfolios_for_Statistical_Arbitrage

Comment: It's page 10, table 6 on the page. Please help explain in layman's terms. Thanks.

Comment: Aha. OK, you need to be much more clear that this spread is *not* a bid-ask spread -- since that is what you seemed to be asking. Instead, we have a spread derived from a cointegrated portfolio of BTC vs ETH, LTC, and BCH. After that, you just use that spread as your variable for time series modeling. In that case, it is not clear what your question is -- unless it is how to fit or modify a time series model (in which case this is the wrong forum for that question).

Comment: @kurtosis thanks. Yes, as you noted the spread of from the cointegration of currency pairs. What's confusing me at the end if the phrase used at the last

Comment: This phrase, what does it mean `Table 6: Fitting the spread to the ARIMA(1, 0, 0) model` . This is on page 10. Can you explain in layman's language. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fitting a spread into ARIMA AR(1)](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/57953/fitting-a-spread-into-arima-ar1)

Comment: Nope.i asked the question earlier and was told to improve it, that's why I called this.